# How to get actual client side URL?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a WordPress contact form which is in a popup. I need to add the same url from which the email was sent to the body. I tried `$body .= '<p>' . wp_get_referer() . '</p>';` but it is printing only the referer page like https://demo.com/page/ but I need the actual URL which is https://demo.com/page/#fdee/1-22

Is there any solution to read the URL at the time the form was submitted?

Answer (score 1):

The anchor fragment/hash is not sent to the server as part of an HTTP request.  Additionally, it's not sent as part of the `Referer` header.  Therefore, it is not accessible via PHP or anything server-side.

You will have to capture that URL client-side with JavaScript and submit it as a hidden form field.

The easiest way to do this is to add a form submit handler which adds the appropriate field:

```
  const formEl = document.querySelector('form');
  formEl.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const referrerEl = document.createElement('input');
    referrerEl.type = 'hidden';
    referrerEl.name = 'referrer';
    referrerEl.value = window.location.toString();
    formEl.appendChild(referrerEl)
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it has to work with JavaScript then. Do you have any working example on how to capture the URL and submit it as an additional field?

Comment: `window.location.hash` is what you need.  I'll write up an example for you in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks. An example would be great to see.

Comment: Brad, thank you for your effort but I could not get this to work. I can paste the whole form code here later.